# create and update custom labels through ToolingAPI

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, metadata-api, tooling-api

How to create and update Custom Label using tooling API? 
Is it possible to do it without deployment? 
Dont want to create and update via Metadata API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tooling API does not have a documented CustomLabel object you can interact with. The list of supported objects are listed in [Tooling API Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm).

On version 42.0, there's two objects that represent labels, CustomLabel and ExternalString. However, attempting to insert, update, or delete labels results in the following error:

```
[ {
  "message" : "entity type cannot be inserted: Custom Label",
  "errorCode" : "CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY",
  "fields" : [ ]
} ]
```

Comment: You can query custom labels using tooling API. Are u sure?

Comment: @SouravNandy It's not in the documentation or the describe call. Are you sure you're not mistaking the Tooling API with the Metadata API?

Comment: Select id,Name from CustomLabel
If i run this in query editor with Using tooling API checkbox it is giving me the values.

Comment: @SouravNandy Okay, so it's new in v42, but it's not documented, and DML operations are restricted.

Comment: yea same result i also got.. just wanted to confirm... If i now go via Metadata API how should i go about..

Comment: @SouravNandy use the CustomLabel object. You do know how to work with it, right? You only need to include the values you wish to insert/update.

Comment: If i do a update call for CustomLabels via Metadata API will there be a deployment for that?

Comment: @SouravNandy Yes, it counts as a deployment. Why do you want to avoid a deployment, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 5):

We can use tooling API to create the custom label and its translation as below.

The Master label is stored in [External String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_externalstring.htm) and translation is stored in [ExternalStringLocalization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_externalstringlocalization.htm)

**Request to create master label:**

Endpoint

```
/services/data/v51.0/tooling/sobjects/ExternalString
```

Payload

```
{
  "Name" : "API_Name_Of_Label",
  "MasterLabel" : "Label of Custom Label",
  "Value" : "Hi, how are you?",
  "IsProtected" : true,
  "Category" : null,
  "Language" : "en_US"
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "id" : "1012v00000NNo06AAD",
  "success" : true,
  "errors" : [ ],
  "warnings" : [ ],
  "infos" : [ ]
}
```

We can grab the Id of Master Label and create translation by creating a record in
**ExternalStringLocalization**. Payload would be like this:

```
{
  "ExternalStringId" : "1012v00000NNo06AAD",
  "Value" : "Salut comment ça va?",
  "Language" : "fr"
}
```

P.S: I came across the requirement to create label using API and did this POC using Workbench and thought to share this.

Comment: did you try to update a few `ExternalStringLocalization` by `/vXX.X/tooling/composite/sobjects`? I have issues getting positive results.